# Do I need ReSharper for Visual Studio 2015/2017

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I saw a lot of good comments about ReSharper. So I gave it a try and I really like it. I even suggested to my team to use it and to put some money in this tool. But they sad "**We better put the money in updating Visual Studio because newer versions come with almost all ReSharper features**" as we are using Visual Studio 2010.

Is ReSharper useless in Visual Studio 2015 or 2017?

Comment: I develop in visual studio for many years and I didn't see any gap that I need resharp er.  But check the comparison link maybe you see some advantages for you: https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/documentation/comparisonMatrix_R9_vs2015.html

Answer (score 5):

This might not be an answer, just my own opinion.

VS2017 is doing very well without R#. however, some important functions are still not there in VS2017, e.g. renaming namespaces, and here R# role arises.

Some where else, I find R# make the things bad, for example, I don't like how the R# renames the properties, it gives and new popup window, where VS2017 renames it immediately.

So what I mean, sometimes R# might be useful, but if you are not using it, you are absolutely safe and productive.

I am still waiting for any video or article where it is described, what are the flagship killers functions in R# which VS2017 doesn't have (except renaming namespaces ;)).

### UPDATE:

What I actually suggest is, install use the refactoring suggestions of R# because they are awesome, but keep the default key mapping of VS2017.**

### UPEATE 2:

I have been working for 1 year without resharper, and I am very ok and do not miss any function, except renaming namespaces.

### UPDATE 3:

I **miss the function of extracting a method to an existing interface** in Visual Studio 2017, which already exists in ReSharper.

Answer (score 3):

ReSharper is not useless in newer versions of Visual Studio, but there are a lot of features and shortcuts that come baked right into VS. My opinion would be that if you are new to developing in VS, look into the features it already has and make the best use of them. After all, what good is a Porsche if you cant drive? Here are a couple of links you should check out.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366750(v=vs.90).aspx